Songs that are so good you wanna cry
Can you name a few songs that are so good you wanna cry. They can be any style or genre. Here are some of mine:

Preliator by Globus - 


Cometh the hour by Shiro Sagisu - 


Tsas Narand Uyarna by Christopher Tin - 


Ethereal (Slowed) by Txmy - 


BELLE by Luc Plamondon - 




Hi Luke, this type of question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange platform. Please ask objective(ly answerable) questions.
